# Why my console.log not appearing in AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have got all `CloudWatchFullAccess` and  `logs:*` access in the execution role of my lambda function, I tried all of the responses in other posts but nothing had work for me..
I only get Request and Responses Mapping..

I don't know what additional infos to share, if there is a need for something just let me know, thank you.

Comment: Giving the Lambda AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole should suffice to allow it to create a log group and write log streams. Is a log stream actually created for your Lambda function invocation? Is your Lambda function actually emitting logs?

Comment: I figured that I get log when I check CloudWatch of the lambda  function but when I am on AppSync testing the query and checking this CloudWatch I don't get it.

Comment: Maybe this is the normal behavior